# Android- Scrollview : change layout position by dragging

Tags: android, scrollview

I create Scrollview with 10 layout.
I want to change the layout position by dragging.

```
layout_view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 

@Override

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
final int action = ev.getAction();  

switch (action) {   
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
...
```

The problem is when i dragging DOWN/UP (When I dragging right/left it's work perfect):

1) MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL happen

2) the Scrollview is moving

1)How Can I disable Scrollview scrolling when I dragging my layout?

2) Do you have any idea how to stay in layout without getting MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a feature that will be easily (if at all) implemented as far as I know. You could try setting the scrollview as not focusable.

Answer (score 1):

Override ScrollView with one that you can enable/disable

```
//A scrollview which can be disabled during drag and drop
public static class OnOffScrollView extends ScrollView {
    private boolean on = true;
    public OnOffScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public OnOffScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public OnOffScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    //turn on the scroll view
    public void enable() {
        on=true;
    }

    //turn off the scroll view
    public void disable() {
        on = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (on) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Disable it in your `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` case, enable it again in the `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` cases